# Tricky URL rewrite, regex .htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have a tricky issue redirecting some URLs internally for my site.

The situation is this, I currently have a URL like `example.com/check/youtube.com` which internally redirects to `check.php?domain=youtube.com` using the following `mod_rewrite` code:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^offline offline.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^error error.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^check/(.*)$ check.php?domain=$1 [NC,L]
```

However I would also like to be able to redirect to `check.php` using a URL like `example.com/youtube.com`. Unfortunately it is just beyond me to figure it out.

I have a directory `/assets/` with all the CSS, JS, etc. which shouldn't be affected.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^[^/.]+\.[^/]+$ check.php?domain=$0 [L]
```

This rule rewrites any request with a URL path of the form `[^/.]+\.[^/]+` (a string that contains at least one dot but no slashes at all) that cannot be mapped to an existing file to your `check.php`.

Comment: Thanks a ton, intreasting that you use $0 as I haven't seen that used before, I'll have to look that up :P

Comment: `$0` is just the matched string of the whole regular expression.

Comment: Ah, yea that makes a lot of sense. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to redirect "example.com/youtube.com" does that mean you wish to redirect pretty much anything? What is specifically allowed to be passed, e.g. would I be allowed to pass "example.com/youtube.com/foobar.php" for a redirect to check.php?

Comment: Well, the script is cleaned via js on submission (there is a note as well for non js users), so if you were to submit *example.com/youtube.com/foobar.php* then it would refresh to *example.com/youtube.com*.

If someone does send that link direct to the script though then it returns a 404. But I will work on that later and it's not a problem.

though if you could clean it with .htaccess instead that would be cool...